# Reallocating memory inside a function and passing by reference in C

Tags: c

I know this may sound stupid but, why is this function I implemented not working properly?

I get the following error in the terminal:

```
cerinta3.c: In function ‘void realocare_memorie(student**, int)’:
cerinta3.c:9:19: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘student*’ [-fpermissive]
    9 |  *vector = realloc(*vector, dimensiune * sizeof(student));
      |            ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                   |
      |                   void*
```

```
void realocare_memorie (student **vector, int dimensiune) {
    *vector = realloc(*vector, dimensiune * sizeof(student));
}
```

Comment: Are you accidentally using C++ instead of C?

Comment: I think this is a rehash of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You compiled your C code through a C++ compiler (`g++` by the error message). This is the signature error of making that mistake. Invoke `gcc` instead.